# How to make internal app available only to API gateway in microservices?

Tags: laravel, microservices

I'm doing micro-service architecture in our app made of Laravel, Lumen. I have an API gateway that forwards the request to internal apps( say auth service is in 8001) then forwards the response to the client side. Other services like user, role etc is in different ports (8002 ...)

How can I make sure that the client can access only the API gateway (in port 80) and not the other internal services? Let say the person (client) is in the same network environment. Firewall? Or am I doing it correctly?

Comment: API gateway could encrypt or sign request, so internal app will verify caller's identity

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a deployment-related concern. The simple solution is to block the internal service ports like `8001` and `8002` to the outside and expose only API gateway to the outside world. And the way to do this depends on the platform as a service(PAAS) or infrastructure as a service (IAAS) that you are using. If you are using a service like Kubernetes to deploy your microservices you can use Kubernetes networking model.